# Cannot load dll in deployed executable

Tags: vb.net, dll, installshield

I have created a program in visual studio which seems to run fine of many machines (the installer is created using installshield). However, on one particular machine the executable cannot load in a dll I am using. I can get around this by running the executable as administrator but this is not a suitable solution. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: You could get better responses with more information. Is the dll managed or native? Have you checked dependencies with static tools like reflector/ilspy or dependency walker, or runtime tools like fuslogvw or loader snaps?

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to answer the question without basic error logs / stack traces / profiling data.  It could be EXE has a dependency on DLL1 which has a dependency on DLL2  and that DLL2 wasn't included in the installer.   It could be that most machines happen to already have DLL2 so DLL 1 loads but on some machines DLL2 is missing so DLL1 won't load.

Installer development is much like other development.  Step 1: Requirements  Step 2: Design  Step3: Construction  Step 4: Testing

Comment: your statement would make sense of it weren't for the fact that the software seems to run successfully when run with administrative privileges

Comment: It was just a high level example.  It's impossible to answer generically.

Comment: I appreciate your help. It is baffling though: i don't understand why it would work on some machines and not others.

Comment: It seems to me that the issue could be permission based and this would explain why run as administrator would work. I do not know how to fix this though.

Comment: You have to root cause it and then it'll make sense.  Could be UAC enabled on some but not others.  It could be registry key or file/folder permissions are different.